# Порядок байт при спектральном анализе WAV файла в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, фурье

Необходимо рассчитать спектр WAV файла. Файл читаю функцией `scipy.io.wavfile.read`. А спектр рассчитываю функцией `scipy.fftpack.fft`. Как известно семалы в WAV файле имеют представление little-endian, то есть сначала идет младший байт, потом старший. Вопрос такой: функция `scipy.fftpack.fft` учитывает это или же представление данных предварительно нужно преобразовать в big-endian?

Comment: а Вы уверенны, что там строго два байта? Более того, там может быть не один канал, а два.

Comment: Да. Все обрабатываемые WAV файлы имеют один канал, размер фрейма 16 бит и частоту дискретизации 44.1 кГц

Comment: Думаю, что scipy.io.wavfile.read выдает данные, которые понимает scipy.fftpack.fft. Но это лекго проверить - возьмите любой редактор аудио и сгенерируйте этот спектр и сравните.

Comment: Вы предлагаете построить график полученного спектра (допустим с помощью Matplotlib) и сравнить со спектром, полученным в редакторе?

Comment: если Вы доверяете Matplotlib, то берите его. Я бы лично сгенерировал сигнал, спектр которого я могу предугадать (например, сумма нескольких синусоид).

Comment: Какую еще библиотеку для построения графиков можете посоветовать? Для подобных экспериментов  к меня есть набор WAV файлов с известными спектрами)

Comment: даже не знаю. я когда то сам их писал. Там работы то собственно на денек:) если знать теорию.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51352/discussion-between---and-kovadim).